# Field not found: 'ImageResizer.Configuration.PluginConfig.LoggingAvailable'

Tags: asp.net, imageresizer, imageresizer-diskcache

I'm using the Image Resizer imageresizing.net. But, when I installed **DiskCache** plugin to serve cached images, an error occurs:

```
Field not found: 'ImageResizer.Configuration.PluginConfig.LoggingAvailable'.
```

Here is my web.config configuration for resizer tag:

```
<code> <resizer>
    <clientcache minutes="1440" />
    <plugins>
      <remove name="DefaultEncoder" />
      <remove name="NoCache" />
      <remove name="ClientCache" />
      <add name="DefaultEncoder" />
      <add name="NoCache" />
      <add name="ClientCache" />
      <add name="DiskCache" />
      <diskCache dir="~/imagecache" autoClean="false" hashModifiedDate="true" enabled="true"
   subfolders="32" cacheAccessTimeout="15000" asyncWrites="false" asyncBufferSize="10485760" />

      <cleanupStrategy startupDelay="00:05" minDelay="00:00:20" maxDelay="00:05"
        optimalWorkSegmentLength="00:00:04"
        targetItemsPerFolder="400" maximumItemsPerFolder="1000"
        avoidRemovalIfCreatedWithin="24:00" avoidRemovalIfUsedWithin="4.00:00"
        prohibitRemovalIfUsedWithin="00:05" prohibitRemovalIfCreatedWithin="00:10" />
    </plugins>
  </resizer></code>
```

Comment: What does [the diagnostics page say?](http://imageresizing.net/support)  Are those HTML tags in your XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of test, I found out that it's simple was a problem about versions.

I have not used the "Nuget.Package.Manager" and update the :

- ImageReziser Web.Config Installation to Version 3.4.3
- ImageReziser.Plugins.DiskCache to Version 3.4.3

And now I don't get this error.